# What is my issue when trying to install rails?

Tags: terminal, software, ruby, rails

[image: I tried updating ruby and this was my feedback]

[image: tried a sudo install and this was my feedback]
I have all the pac managers and etc that i can get from any book or online resources anywhere, ive tried many methods and just about everything i can find online. Can someone who knows exactly what the issue is inform me on the solution.

Comment: Did you read the error message that says you need Ruby 2.2.2 or newer? Run `ruby --version` if you need to check.

Comment: When you post output, please don't take a screenshot unless absolutely necessary.  It's better to cut and paste code into your original quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Ruby.

1. Install home-brew (It will allow you to install software package from source): `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install ruby:

   - `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
   - `echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile`
   - `source ~/.bash_profile`
   - `rbenv install 2.3.1`
   - `rbenv global 2.3.1`
3. Check which version you have (It should show 2.3.1): `ruby -v`
4. Install Rails:

   - `gem install rails -v 4.2.6`
   - `rbenv rehash`
5. Check Rails Version: `rails -v`

I hope it helps you

[Source](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite)